# How to know if twitter user is logged in?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache

I'm currently developing something related to twitter activity, i first want to confirm if user is logged in twitter.com using any of their apis or something, how is it possible ?

Comment: yup, and im asking to lead me to the right/better solution

Comment: @Osa: better than what? Better than nothing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to check if an arbitrary user is currently logged in (meaning they have an active OAuth token or unexpired cookie) from somewhere around the world through twitter's APIs.

Comment: well, could it be done by sending a live request to twitter.com and check if user is cookies are active ?, lets say i send an ajax request to twitter.com, is it possible to check some exist element that confirms he's logged in ?

Comment: @Osa other than checking the feed and seeing if there was a tweet recently, it isn't possible. Twitter wouldn't want to allow users to arbitrarily check other's user's active cookies.